# Как детектировать программу занимающую CPU в Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Без привязки к ЯП как можно детектировать программу потребляющую много процессорного времени(майнер)? По имени процесса - врятле, по хешу исполняемого файла - тоже не подойдет. какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Открыть диспетчер задач и посмотреть .. вариант?

Comment: Так и детектировать. По потреблению процессорного времени

Comment: @Kromster нужно программно, типа найти и обезвредить

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, а как высчитывать потребленное процессорное время, и отличать его от других программ нагружающих процессор?

Comment: msdn [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx) или GetSystemInfo, самая первая подфункция даст список процессов и процент. Дальше обрабатывайте - детектируйте

Comment: Отличить - никак. Вы же сами дали определение "враг тот, кто много жрет"

Answer (score 3):

Например, так получить top(3) в PS (alias ps=[Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7)):

```
PS C:\> ps | select id,name,cpu | sort -des cpu | select -f 3

   Id Name           CPU
   -- ----           ---
13112 chrome 23388,71875
15848 chrome 14001,34375
15352 chrome    8798,125
```